# Retrieve multiple hash from redis and compare key-values to another dict or hash using python

Tags: python, hash, redis

My data is stored in redis in multiple hashes. I need to match these hashes to a dictionary of same keys and if values are same for these keys, all those hashes need to be retrieved. I am new to Redis and could not find a solution.

```
red_db.hset("trip1", "Customer_associated", "Garima")
red_db.hset("trip1", "trip_date", "06/09/2019")
red_db.hset("trip1", "trip_source", "Hyderabad")
red_db.hset("trip1", "trip_destination", "Banglore")
red_db.hset("trip2", "Customer_associated", "Sravya")
red_db.hset("trip2", "trip_date", "06/09/2019")
red_db.hset("trip2", "trip_source", "Hyderabad")
red_db.hset("trip2", "trip_destination", "Vijaywada")
red_db.hset("trip3", "Customer_associated", "Kartik")
red_db.hset("trip3", "trip_date", "06/09/2019")
red_db.hset("trip3", "trip_source", "Banglore")
red_db.hset("trip3", "trip_destination", "Vijaywada")
print(red_db.hgetall("trip1"))
```

Now, I have

```
req1 = {'User_Id': 1, 'trip_date':"06/09/2019",'trip_source':"Hyderabad", 'trip_destination':"Banglore"}
```

How to get all the matching hashes(trip1/trip2/trip3)

Comment: Did you check http://redisearch.io?

Comment: Yes. But that's not what is required.